# "kindly request that something IS cancelled", or "WILL BE cancelled?"

Tags: verbs, tenses, expression-choice

Which is the correct usage?

> 1. We kindly request that the phone line **is** cancelled.
> 2. We kindly request that the phone line **will be** cancelled.

Comment: This is either proofreading or an [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) question.

Comment: @Sirma. My pleasure and welcome to EL&U. Please make sure that you take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Comment: "We kindly request that the phone line be cancelled."

Comment: Aside from the question of which form of the verb *to be* is appropriate here, I would note that kindness characterizes rather the granting than the making of a request.